# Copy a row with multiple criteria in Excel VBA even if some of cells are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a row from `sheet1` to `sheet2` with multiple criteria.

My code does not work when some of the cells are empty within the row where other criteria are met.

```vb
Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(49, 8)).Clear    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim client As String
    Dim bLength As String
    Dim span As String
    Dim height As String
    Dim baySpacing As String
    Dim siteLocation As String
    Dim comments As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lastrowb As Long

    client = TextBox1.Text
    bLength = TextBox2.Value
    span = TextBox3.Value
    height = TextBox4.Value
    baySpacing = TextBox5.Value
    siteLocation = TextBox6.Text
    comments = TextBox7.Text

    Lastrow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrowb = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = 3 To Lastrow
        
        If InStr(UCase(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Text), UCase(client)) And _
           InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, bLength) And _
           InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value, span) And _
           InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value, height) And _
           InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value, baySpacing) And _
           InStr(UCase(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Text), UCase(siteLocation)) And _
           InStr(UCase(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Text), UCase(comments)) Then

            Sheets(1).Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(Lastrowb)
            Lastrowb = Lastrowb + 1
            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I want a copy even if any of the cells are empty when other criteria meet.

Comment: For each of your tests, use `(IsEmpty(YourCell) Or Instr(...) And ...`

Comment: Thanks for your advise mate. But it returns all row, not shorting when other column matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function (and a `With` block) to simplify your checks:

```
For i = 3 To Lastrow
    With Sheets(1).Rows(i)
        If HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 1).Text), UCase(client)) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 2).Value, bLength) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 3).Value, span) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 4).Value, height) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 5).Value, baySpacing) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 6).Text), UCase(siteLocation)) And _
           HasOrEmpty(.Cells(i, 7).Text), UCase(comments)) Then

           .Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(Lastrowb)
           Lastrowb = Lastrowb + 1

        End If
    End With
Next
```

The function:

```
'return true if txt is empty or "lookFor" is contained in "Txt"
Function HasOrEmpty(txt, lookFor)
    HasOrEmpty = Len(txt)=0 Or InStr(txt, lookFor) > 0
End Function
```